# Moq Verify Fails - Unit Test Fails When Run in Batch, Succeeds When Run Singularly

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I'm finding this Unit Test behaviour very strange.  If I run this unit test on its own it is successful, every time.

If I run it along with the other tests in the same class, it fails.  I could understand it if there was anything shared with other tests at runtime but as far as I can see all the objects in use in this test are created specifically for this test.

```
public void AttemptLoginFailsEmailValidates()
{
    const string emailAddress = "test@test.com";
    const string password = "Password";

    ClearAll();

    var moqSettingsService = new Mock<ISettingsService>();
    var moqLoginService = new Mock<ILoginService>();
    var moqMessenger = new Mock<IMvxMessenger>();
    var moqDialogService = new Mock<IDialogService>();

    var validationService = new ValidatorService();
    moqLoginService.Setup(li => li.Login(It.Is<string>(s => s == emailAddress), It.Is<string>(s => s == password), false, It.Is<string>(s => s == "User"))).Returns(Task.FromResult(false));

    var vm = new LoginViewModel(moqLoginService.Object, moqSettingsService.Object, validationService, moqDialogService.Object, moqMessenger.Object) { EmailLogin = emailAddress, Password = password };

    Assert.AreEqual(emailAddress, vm.EmailLogin);
    Assert.AreEqual(password, vm.Password);

    vm.LoginCommand.Execute(new object());

    moqLoginService.Verify(p => p.Login(It.Is<string>(s => s == emailAddress), It.Is<string>(s => s == password), false, It.Is<string>(s => s == "User")), Times.Once);
}
```

The Moq exception is:

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: p => p.Login(It.Is<String>(s => s == "test@test.com"), It.Is<String>(s => s == "Password"), False, It.Is<String>(s => s == "User"))

Configured setups:
li => li.Login(It.Is<String>(s => s == "test@test.com"), It.Is<String>(s => s == "Password"), False, It.Is<String>(s => s == "User")), Times.Never
No invocations performed.
```

Comment: I'd wager it's something static in the sut that's not being reset between tests though without seeing the LoginViewModel it's hard to say.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, but there isn't anything static in any of the classes in use.

Comment: What does `ClearAll` do?  Do you get the same problem if you run a subset of the tests in the class, rather than all of them?  If you remove this test from the run, but execute the rest of the tests in the class does a different test fail instead?  Try to reduce the number of tests required to reproduce the problem, then have another look at those tests to see if there are any overlaps.

Comment: Good ideas!  Will have a poke around as I moved onto different tasks!